# Angular 2, Constructor and ngOnInit not getting called if route is manipulated using url address bar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am accessing certain route eg: http://xyz.domain.com/profile/1. Now when i manipulate the same url with parameter 2 i.e http://xyz.domain.com/profile/2, the component associated with this route is not getting activated that is OnInit is not getting called. Does any one have idea why is that behavior ? Can anyone help on this

Comment: Please post some code to have the chance to see potential mistakes.

Comment: @DiabolicWords this isn't a mistake, that's a shady Angular behavior. He is asking for an explanation, and for once, I don't think it's in the documentation.

Comment: OnInit will only fire once the component was loaded. So changing params will not fire the OnInit again. It should work if you put those code inside the curly braces of constructor instead

Comment: Neither constructor is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your component isn't destroyed. If you stay on the same route, then you neither destroy your component, nor recreate it.

If you want to see an example of this behavior, [feel free to look at this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nkzsc?file=app%2Frouted%2Frouted.component.ts).

If you want to make something on same URL navigation, you will have to listen to routing events, and do something when it ends. Something like this.

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
  this.ngOnInit();
});
```

Comment: Great thanks! This works. But does this means i have to do for every component ?

Comment: Only for the components you want to "reload". Until now, I haven't figured out how to do it in another way. I tried with `router.onSameUrlNavigation`, but it doesn't seem to do a thing ...

Comment: And if you don't want to do it on every component, you can make a decorator or a superclass for that. If you need help, feel free to ask !

Comment: Ok great!! Thanks really helped a lot. But if i am doing route navigation this will again call onInit, but i only need to recall for the same route

Comment: @user5309516 if you unsubscribe from the events, it should not trigger on route change. Otherwise `event` contains the URL you're currently on, so you can try to see if the URL matches your component.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps anyone as per @trichetriche comment

```
 // ... your class variables here
 navigationSubscription;

this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
  this.ngOnInit();
});
```

Now on ngDestroy we need to unsubscribe it else on following router events will make the ngOnInit() called for every route instance even in case of normal navigation.

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    // method on every navigationEnd event.
    if (this.navigationSubscription) {  
       this.navigationSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I precised that in the comments, and unsubscribing isn't related to the routing issue, it is related to how you decide to handle your subscriptions. Downvote for vulturing.

Comment: Okay. Great I din't saw that. So thought if it helps anyone in future

Comment: I didnt vulture for your accomplishment it's just i noted and posted.

Comment: Sorry if it was offensive, that's just a language shortcut I used. You basically said that my answer was correct but incomplete, and add something I stated in the comments. This makes your answer trivial.

Comment: I posted the answer it's you mentioned about the comment than i saw it's just misunderstanding anyways. The issue was resolved by you only. I just felt need to add